# Best practice to reference the parent activity of a fragment?

Tags: android

I've been working a lot with fragments lately and I was just curious as to what the best practice is for using a reference to a fragment's parent activity. Would it be better to keep calling getActivity() or have a parentActivity variable initialized on the onActivityCreated callback.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is actually included in the official Android document on Fragments.  When you need the context of the parent activity (e.g. Toast, Dialog), you would call `getActivity()`.  When you need to invoke the callback methods in your Fragment's interface, you should use a callback variable that is instantiated in `onAttach(...)`.

```
public static class FragmentA extends ListFragment {
    ExampleFragmentCallbackInterface mListener;
    ...
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        try {
            mListener = (ExampleFragmentCallbackInterface ) context;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(context.toString() + " must implement ExampleFragmentCallbackInterface ");
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

[Source](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#EventCallbacks)

Comment: Using FragmentCallbackInterface is my preferred way to implement this.

Comment: @James: Can you please explain why this approach is better than using getActivity() ? Sometimes getActivity() returns null and the app crashes. By using the above approach, can one be sure that app won't crash ? Thanks.

Comment: If getActivity() is returning null then you haven't been attached yet so `mListener` would also be null.  This approach is better than using `getActivity()` because it ensures whatever activity you are attached to implements the interface needed to work with the content in the fragment.

Comment: `onAttach(Activity activity)` is now deprecated in API 23, so this is no longer valid http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onAttach(android.app.Activity)

Answer (score 9):

getActivity() is best. You need not maintain a variable to store (always, til app cycle!). If needed invoke the method and use! :)

Comment: getActivity() returns null when an activity is recreated.( For example permission changes from settings.)

Answer (score -1):

If you are in the fragment which is called from some activity, to get the reference to parent activity you can call it inside onViewCreated() or later hook methods of fragment directly by, it is just to make sure that parent activity is not null

```
getActivity()
```

If you want to really make sure you need to check first

```
if (getActivity() != null){ // then your logic with getActivity()}
```

Comment: Can someone explain why this answer is downvoted so much? What is the bad practice here?

Comment: I am not sure either