# Passing data From Activity to Fragment using interface

Tags: android, android-fragments, interface

I want to pass data from an activity to a fragment, using an interface.
Please have a look at the code snippets below:

Interface:

```
public interface FragmentCommunicator {

   public void passData(String name);
}
```

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    FragmentCommunicator fragmentCommunicator;
    private Fragment fragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                fragment= new Fragment();
                fragmentCommunicator = (FragmentCommunicator) getApplication();
                fragmentCommunicator.passData("hello");
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container ,fragment).commit();

            }
        });

    }
}
```

Fragment:

```
public class Fragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment implements FragmentCommunicator {

    FragmentCommunicator communicator;
    Context c;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, null);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        this.c = context;

    }
    @Override
    public void passData(String name) {
        Toast.makeText(c, name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

I just want to pass some string when I click on button, (or some other event) to launch a fragment, and when the fragment is launched, it should show a toast containing that string...

Please help
any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How to pass from activity to fragment - http://stackoverflow.com/a/9245510/6254066

Comment: @AgileNinja I said I want to pass data using interface not by bundle.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Write this line of code after onCreate method.

```
public void passVal(FragmentCommunicator fragmentCommunicator) {
    this.fragmentCommunicator = fragmentCommunicator;
}
```

Something like this

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

FragmentCommunicator fragmentCommunicator;
private Fragment fragment;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    fragment= new Fragment();

    //App is crasing for this line. Working fine by removing it
    //fragmentCommunicator = (FragmentCommunicator) getApplication();

    //fragmentCommunicator.passData("hello");
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container ,fragment).commit();

    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            fragmentCommunicator.passData("Hello");

        }
    });

  }

   //Here is new method
   public void passVal(FragmentCommunicator fragmentCommunicator) {
       this.fragmentCommunicator = fragmentCommunicator;

   }
}
```

Then write this line of code into onCreateView() of your fragment. Something like this

```
@Override 
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup  container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, null);

((MainActivity) getActivity()).passVal(new FragmentCommunicator() {
       @Override
       public void passData(String name) {
           Toast.makeText(c, name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
   });
  return view;
}
```

Note: no need to implement FragmentCommunicator interface in your fragment. Hope it works. It works for me. I have tested

Comment: from where should I start my fragment? i.e beginTransaction?

Comment: Code is updated try again.

Comment: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to com.example.akshaysood.interfacecallback.FragmentCommunicator

Comment: Do you want to pass value by pressing any button or fragment initial time?

Comment: I want to pass the value with click on the button and at the same time the fragment should be launched

Comment: So Why are you using interface? you can do that easily with setArgument of bundle. Interface purpose is you can any time passing value to fragment from activity. its not wise in launch time

Comment: I want to know this one also

Comment: fragmentCommunicator = (FragmentCommunicator) getApplication();  What this line does?

Comment: This answer was helpful for setting Interfaces while using Navigation components

Answer (score 1):

Activities contain fragments, you shouldn't need to pass anything.  One technique would be to store your data in the activity scope and get a reference to it with getActivity().

[Best practice to reference the parent activity of a fragment?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13116104/4552124)

As far as the code you posted, I don't see where you call your pass data method within the fragment.  I would suggest calling it in onviewcreated().

I will attempt to provide some sample code later as doing this on my mobile device is proving difficult.

Try passdata (getActivity ().someStringVariable);

Comment: how will I pass the data and access the data can you write a simple example?

Answer (score 0):

In your `Fragment` class, have a `TAG` field. Naming a fragment `Fragment` can be a bit confusing as it is the same name as an Android `Fragment`, so I will use `ExampleFragment`:

```
public class ExampleFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment implements FragmentCommunicator {
    public static final String TAG = "ExampleFragment";

    // ...
}
```

Now, when you replace the fragment in the activity, make sure to pass the `TAG`:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container ,fragment, ExampleFragment.TAG).commit();
```

Note that in your case it would be `Fragment.TAG`, but I used `ExampleFragment` to clarify that `Fragment.TAG` is not part of the Android SDK.

To get a reference of your fragment in your activity, use the `FragmentManager` to find your fragment:

```
Fragment myFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(ExampleFragment.TAG);
```

You can then make sure that `myFragment` is not `null` and cast it to `FragmentCommunicator`:

```
if (myFragment != null) {
    fragmentCommunicator = (FragmentCommunicator) myFragment;
}
```

Note that in your example `fragmentCommunicator = (FragmentCommunicator) getApplication();` is invalid because it is your fragment that is implementing the interface, not your application.