# Custom interface not working on Activity

Tags: java, android

I'm still new in creating interface. I refer a lot of tutorial but still not working. I want to pass the value from activity to fragment. mListener is null.

How the call the listener in correct way ?

**Interface**

```
public interface ListenerCardDetails {
    void getCardSelected(String id);
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class CardDetailsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ListenerCardDetails mListener;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // some stuff
    mListener.getCardSelected("20");
}

public void setListener(ListenerCardDetails mListener) {
        this.mListener = mListener;
    }
```

**MyFragment.java**

```
public class TabPoints extends Fragment implements ListenerCardDetails {

    private CardDetailsActivity mCardDetailsActivity;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab_points, container, false);
        configView(view);
        return view;
    }

    private void configView(View view){
        ((CardDetailsActivity) getActivity()).setListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void getCardSelected(String id) {
         Toast.makeText(getActivity(), id, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

**Error**

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity
>   java.lang.InstantiationException:
>   java.lang.Class
>   has no zero argument constructor
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2548)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
>   Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException:
>   java.lang.Class
>   has no zero argument constructor
>                         at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: You can't `instantiate` your activity.

Comment: Check this one : [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37122385/5816000)
This might help you.

Comment: Please remove the constructor from the activity. Instead use a static method in activity and call it from the fragment to instantiate the listener.

Comment: @Piyush could you please provide an answer

Comment: @VaibhavJain could you please write your answer

Comment: @Bishu that one is not listener right ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Communicating between a fragment and an activity - best practices.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14247954/communicating-between-a-fragment-and-an-activity-best-practices)

Comment: Yours main problem is actually wrong usage of Activities and fragments. The `interface` is the last thing here.

Comment: How does look like the association between the Activity and Fragment?
Who hosts the the fragment? Because if the `CardDetailsActivity` then the `onCreate` method is called before `onCreateView` in fragment. So the NPE is unavoidable.

Comment: The value will be retrieve at activity, then pass to fragment. So, onCreate method is called first then mListeners is keep null right ? What is the solution ? hmmm

Comment: Yes, the `onCreate` is called first. Before doing something in Android you should first become more familiar with the framework itself. There is nice diagram about the lifecycle: https://plus.google.com/photos/photo/101826485820997153590/5914215085941005954?icm=false

Comment: @Sariyanti Please post a code which will explain us where is the fragment actually put. Is it in layout?

Comment: @jakubbialkowski, I'm using a viewpager for the fragment. It didnt put in any layout.

Comment: @Sariyanti Then please show the layout of Activity with ViewPager and how do you set the ViewPager adapter.

Answer (score 2):

doing this

```
new CardDetailsActivity(this);
```

is not the way android wants you to create activities at all, your code is not working because basiccally you are creating a TOTALLY NEW instance of the activity, not keeping in mind all the preparation the framework does for you in the background...

solution can be:

take the activity and add a new method where you set the listener interface!

Comment: can you give me an example on creating new method ?

Comment: The solution with setting custom listener is error prone because of way how android system will recreate the `Activity` and `Fragments` in case of being destroyed by system.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> Unable to instantiate activity java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class has no zero argument constructor
> ```

This tells you exactly what happened. In Android you are not allowed to create any `Activity` or `Fragment` with custom constructor.
It is because the Android framework uses reflection under the hood to instantiate them.

If you want to communicate between `Activity` and `Fragment` you should use the `onAttach(Context context)` in `Fragment`.

Please refer to the official docs of Android https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Comment: If you dont want to help, please dont sabotage my question. Sigh.

Comment: The link to the official documentation is going to help you. Just read the documentation carefully.

Answer (score 0):

How you can do is, define `Interface` in your `Fragment` and add `void getCardSelected(String id);` method to that. Implement the same interface in your `Activity` and override the interface method and write your logic inside that method.

[For more explanation follow this tutorial](http://simpledeveloper.com/how-to-communicate-between-fragments-and-activities/)

If you want to send values from `Activity` to `Fragment` then follow this link:  [Send data from activity to fragment in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12739909/send-data-from-activity-to-fragment-in-android)

Hope it will help you.

Comment: I want to pass the value from activity to fragment.

Comment: Please check edited answer. And still if you want to do it using `Interface` then do reverse. (Declare `Interface` in `Activity` and implement it in `Fragment`)

Comment: I want to use listener instead of Bundle. Is it ok ?

Comment: yeah you can try doing reverse then. As i've described in above comment

Answer (score 0):

do not use custom constructor, but put on a setListener instead.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ListenerCardDetails mListener;

    public void setListener(ListenerCardDetails mListener) {
        this.mListener = mListener;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // some stuff
        mListener.getCardSelected("20");
    }


    public class TabPoints extends Fragment implements ListenerCardDetails {

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab_points, container, false);
            configView(view);
            return view;
        }

        private void configView(View view){
            ((MainActivity) getActivity()).setListener(this);
        }


        @Override
        public void getCardSelected(String id) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), id, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void xx.xxx.com.xxx.callback.ListenerCardDetails.getCardSelected(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Comment: use getCardSelected before fragment set

Comment: use this  if(mListener !=null) mListener.getCardSelected("20");

Comment: mListener is null. getCardSelected was called at Activity not fragment.

Answer (score 0):

try this `public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
    private ListenerCardDetails mListener;

    public void setListener(ListenerCardDetails mListener) {
        this.mListener = mListener;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TabPoints fragmentListingMyGrid = new TabPoints();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.hidesContainer, fragmentListingMyGrid);

        fragmentListingMyGrid.setCardSelected("20");
    }

}

public class TabPoints extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab_points, container, false);
        return view;
    }

    public void setCardSelected(String id) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), id, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}`
```

Comment: What are u trying to do ? Make a bluff ?

Answer (score 0):

In your `CardDetailActivity` change the function `setListener` like this :

```
public static void setListener(ListenerCardDetails mListener) {
    this.mListener = mListener;
}
```

Now in you `TabPoints` fragment replace :

```
((CardDetailsActivity) getActivity()).setListener(this);
```

with :

```
CardDetailActivity.setListener(this);
```

> OR

In your **CardDetailActivity.java**

```
public class CardDetailsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        TabPoints.bindListener(new ListenerCardDetails(){
            @Override
            public void getCardSelected(String id) {
                Toast.makeText(CardDetailsActivity.this, id, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
         }
    }
}
```

In your **TabPoints.java**

```
public class TabPoints extends Fragment {
ListenerCardDetails mListener;
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab_points, container, false);
    return view;
    configView(view);

}

private void configView(View view){
    mListener.getCardSelected(20);
}

public static void bindListener(ListenerCardDetails listener) {
    mListener = listener;
}
```

Comment: `mListener.getCardSelected(20)` should be obtain from activity not fragment.