# Shared Element Transition from Fragment to Activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, animation

I already read articles about that like this [one](https://mikescamell.com/shared-element-transitions-part-4-recyclerview/index.html), I achieved that but i have a problem:

I'm trying to do a shared element transition between an Activity and a Fragment:

From my Activity I call a Fragment,
When I click on an element of this fragment I want to start the transition from the fragment back to my activity.

I implemented that and is working, for call back my starting activity I'm using:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MyActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(TRANSITION_NAME, ViewCompat.getTransitionName(sharedView));

    ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(getActivity(), p1, p2);
    startActivity(intent, options.toBundle());
```

The problem is that doing that I'm creating a NEW activity, I just want to call back my old one from where the fragment has been called and do the transition.

How Can I achieve that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best practice to reference the parent activity of a fragment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13116104/best-practice-to-reference-the-parent-activity-of-a-fragment)

Comment: I don't need the context of my activity, I need to close the fragment and run the shared element transition returning in the old activity